# Dereferencing in XML::Atom::Feed

Tags: perl

Stackoverflow's feeds are Atom feeds and I was not able to parse them using [`XML::RSS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::RSS) itself and have tried other parsers that are currently developed but still unsuccessful. The closest that I have got to parsing out the feeds was with the [`XML::Atom::Feed`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Atom::Feed) module, but can not wrap my brain around dereferencing the link objects of the entries.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use XML::Atom::Feed;

my $url  = 'http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=r&sort=newest';

my $feed = XML::Atom::Feed->new(URI->new($url)) 
                or die XML::Atom::Feed->errstr;

for ($feed->entries) {
  say $_->title, "\n", $_->link;
}
```

Which outputs the latest thirty entries as follows:

```
Rcpp: Returning C array as NumericMatrix to R
XML::Atom::Link=HASH(0x24cbf00)
```

I was aware that the link object was a hash reference but I seem to be missing something.

Also, is there another module better for parsing XML Atom feeds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML::Atom is not very thoroughly documented. It's quite a good collection of modules once you figure it out though. Anyway, links are blessed objects with various methods available, including `href`.

Try something like:

```
for ($feed->entries) {
  say $_->title, "\n", $_->link->href;
}
```

The source code for [XML::Atom::Link](https://metacpan.org/source/XML::Atom::Link) will show you the other methods available. It's mostly pretty easy to follow.

Comment: I accepted your answer since you first provided the correct implementation of the `href()` method and the source.

Answer (score 2):

As [`XML::Atom::Feed`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Atom::Feed#feed-link) documentation states, `link()` method is context sensitive, so depending on what you need you might want to use scalar context, either by forcing by `scalar` or implicit scalar context when assigning to `$link`,

```
for ($feed->entries) {
  my $link = $_->link;
  say $_->title, "\n", $link->href;
}
```

Comment: Yes now I do, I couldn't find any documentation for it before. Thanks.

Comment: `$_` is an [XML::Atom::Entry](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Atom::Entry), not an [XML::Atom::Feed](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Atom::Feed). (Though as it happens, the behaviour of the `link()` method is identical in both, as they inherit it from an abstract base class.)

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Atom::Feed) says, the `link()` method returns an object of type [XML::Atom::Link](https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/XML-Atom-0.41/lib/XML/Atom/Link.pm). Documentation for that class is non-existent, but it seems that it has an `href()` method which gives the result that you want.

```
for ($feed->entries) {
  say $_->title, "\n", $_->link->href;
}
```